# EaselJS: Stretching Shape to a Specific Side

Tags: javascript, canvas, transform, easeljs

By default all shapes stretch symmetrically from the center of the shape. Is it possible to stretch a shape to specific side?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Things "stretch" from their origin point. If you draw from the center, and then scale, then it will appear to scale from the center.

Draw rectangle from center

```
var r1 = new createjs.Shape();
r1.graphics.beginStroke("red").drawRect(-100,-100,200,200);
```

Draw rectangle from left

```
var r2 = new createjs.Shape();
r2.graphics.beginStroke("red").drawRect(0,0,200,200);
```

Here is a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/owx26481/

Alternately you can change the registration point, which basically offsets where the object is drawn from, and has the same effect:

```
var r1 = new createjs.Shape();
r1.graphics.beginStroke("red").drawRect(0,0,200,200);

var r2 = new createjs.Shape();
r2.graphics.beginStroke("red").drawRect(0,0,200,200); // SAME

r2.regX = r2.regY = 100; // Change registration point to the center (50%)
```

Here is an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/owx26481/2

I hope that makes sense!

Comment: Thank you for a thorough explanation! I forgot to mention that in my case shapes could be rotated sometimes. Rotation factor breaks standard x&y logics, because x axis of a shape and x axis of the canvas don't match.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately that gets into more complicated math. You could instead put your content in a container, and offset your contents inside the container as necessary. You could also look into Dan Zen's ZIM framework for CreateJS, which provides a lot of features like that. http://zimjs.com/ -- Here is a short video on his Transformable container: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p0zsMNVPaXU